# GLSL(OpenGL Shader) varying custom interpolation?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

Generally in opengl shader,

```cpp
varying vColor
 void main() {
   gl_FragColor = vColor;
}
```

Then result is [image]

But what i want to get is [image]

The question is, can I use my custom interpolation to get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely you can. Passing a float attribute indicating position in your own interpolation, or use a varying float variable for it.

```
varying float t;
void main() {
    t = clamp(t * 4.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl_FragColor = mix(vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0), t);
}
```